# ListsfromList function in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I writing a predicate in prolog in which I give two parameters `listsFromL(X,B)`. `X` would be a list with lists within that list and `B` would be a new list with the lists from `X`.

So, for example, if I would call `listsFromL([1,2,[d,a]],X).` the return would be `B = [[d,a]].` and if I would add more lists to `X` I would get a longer list with lists as `X`.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listsFromList([],[]) .

listsFromList([HEAD|SOURCEs],[HEAD|TARGETs])
:-
is_list(HEAD) ,
listsFromList(SOURCEs,TARGETs)
.

listsFromList([HEAD|SOURCEs],TARGETs)
:-
\+ is_list(HEAD) ,
listsFromList(SOURCEs,TARGETs)
.
```

```
/*
?- listsFromList([1,2,3,4,[a,b]],X).
X = [[a, b]] ;
false.

?- listsFromList([1,[a,b],2,[c,d],3],X).
X = [[a, b], [c, d]] ;
false.

?- listsFromList([],X).
X = [].

?- 
*/
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the comment. Could you maybe elaborate a bit on how the code works. I am trying really hard to understand, I get that you recursively check if the head of the list is a list, but I don't really get when/how you add the head to the new list if it is a list. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second clause contains `[HEAD|TARGETs]` . That means that the `HEAD` is added to the output list . The third clause contains merely `TARGETs` . That means that the `HEAD` is not added to the output list .

Comment: Yeah I figured haha... Thankss

Comment: So this is a head recursive/ left recursive way. How would you go about it in a tail recursive way?

Comment: "tail-recursive" means something important and particular in Prolog that meaning is different than Your use of it .

Comment: @leximus I added another answer showing right recursion .

Comment: thanks thanks, why am I using it wrong? How would you explain the difference?

Comment: and if you have time.. otherwise just ignore.. one last question: if you want to add each item separately in stead of the entire list to the new list how would you add  that. So for example listsFromList([1,2,[a,b,c],3,4,[d,e]],X). Would give X = [a, b, c, d, e] .

Answer (score 2):

You need:

1. A predicate to filter you original list: one which detects lists: [`is_list/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=is_list/1)
2. A "higher-order" predicate that, given the above, filters a list which may contains lists into a list with only the lists: [`include/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3)

Now you just need to put those two Lego blocks together.

```
listsFromList(Stuff,OnlyLists) :-
   include(is_list,Stuff,OnlyLists).
```

And so:

```
?- listsFromList([],OLs).
OLs = [].

?- listsFromList([a,b,c],OLs).
OLs = [].

?- listsFromList([a,b,[x,y],c],OLs).
OLs = [[x, y]].
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting first of all. I understand that the is_list function, but I don't know what you mean with the include function. So far I came up with this              accLists([H|T],LL) :- is_list(H), append(LL,H,NEWLIST), LL is NEWLIST, T. 
accLists([H|T],LL) :- \+ is_list(H) = false, LL is LL, T.

lists(List,LL) :- accLists(List, LL).
listsFromList(List,LL) :- lists(List,LL).                                                                                            I am very new to this language and don't really understand how I am able to recursively go through the list.

Comment: @leximus Ok, there is a "detailed coding" and an "industrial" solution. Kintalken shows you a detailed one. This one is "industrial", using predefined blocks. I have only a few minutes left, I will add it above.

Comment: Thanks a lot man!! I don't know if Iam allowed to use it, but I'll ask that haha. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
listsFromList(SOURCEs,TARGETs)
:-
phrase(listsFromList_,SOURCEs,TARGETs)
.

listsFromList_,[] --> \+ [_] .

listsFromList_,[ITEM] --> [ITEM] , { is_list(ITEM) }  , listsFromList_ .

listsFromList_,[] --> [ITEM] , { \+ is_list(ITEM) } , listsFromList_ .
```

```
/*

?- listsFromList([1,2,3,4,[a,b]],X).
X = [[a, b]] ;
false.

?- listsFromList([1,2,[b,c],3,4,[a,b]],X).
X = [[b, c], [a, b]] ;
false.

?- listsFromList([],X).
X = [] ;
false.

?- 
*/
```